# Using jsoup to escape disallowed tags

Tags: java, html, jsoup, xss, htmlcleaner

I am evaluating [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) for the functionality which would sanitize (but not remove!) the non-whitelisted tags. Let's say only `<b>` tag is allowed, so the following input

```
foo <b>bar</b> <script onLoad='stealYourCookies();'>baz</script>
```

has to yield the following:

```
foo <b>bar</b> &lt;script onLoad='stealYourCookies();'&gt;baz&lt;/script&gt;
```

I see the following problems/questions with jsoup:

- `document.getAllElements()` always assumes `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>`. Yes, I can call `document.body().getAllElements()` but the point is that I don't know if my source is a full HTML document or just the body -- and I want the result in the same shape and form as it came in;
- how do I replace `<script>...</script>` with `&lt;script&gt;...&lt;/script&gt;`? I only want to replace brackets with escaped entities and do not want to alter any attributes, etc. `Node.replaceWith` sounds like an overkill for this.
- Is it possible to completely switch off pretty printing (e.g. insertion of new lines, etc.)?

Or maybe I should use another framework? I have peeked at [htmlcleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) so far, but the given examples don't suggest my desired functionality is supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Answer 1

How do you load / parse your `Document` with Jsoup? If you use `parse()` or `connect().get()` jsoup will automaticly format your html (inserting `html`, `body` and `head` tags). This this *ensures* you always have a complete Html document - even if input isnt complete.

Let's assume you only want to clean an input (no furhter processing) you should use `clean()` instead the previous listed methods.

**Example 1 - Using parse()**

```
final String html = "<b>a</b>";

System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(html));
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <b>a</b>
 </body>
</html>
```

Input html is completed to ensure you have a complete document.

**Example 2 - Using clean()**

```
final String html = "<b>a</b>";

System.out.println(Jsoup.clean("<b>a</b>", Whitelist.relaxed()));
```

**Output:**

```
<b>a</b>
```

Input html is cleaned, not more.

**Documentation:**

- [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html)

---

## Answer 2

The method `replaceWith()` does exactly what you need:

**Example:**

```
final String html = "<b><script>your script here</script></b>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

for( Element element : doc.select("script") )
{
    element.replaceWith(TextNode.createFromEncoded(element.toString(), null));
}

System.out.println(doc);
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <b>&lt;script&gt;your script here&lt;/script&gt;</b>
 </body>
</html>
```

Or **body only**:

```
System.out.println(doc.body().html());
```

**Output:**

```
<b>&lt;script&gt;your script here&lt;/script&gt;</b>
```

**Documentation:**

- [Node.replaceWith(Node in)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#replaceWith%28org.jsoup.nodes.Node%29)
- [TextNode](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.html)

---

## Answer 3

Yes, `prettyPrint()` method of `Jsoup.OutputSettings` does this.

**Example:**

```
final String html = "<p>your html here</p>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);

System.out.println(doc);
```

*Note:* if the `outputSettings()` method is not available, please update Jsoup.

**Output:**

```
<html><head></head><body><p>your html here</p></body></html>
```

**Documentation:**

- [Document.OutputSettings.prettyPrint(boolean pretty)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.OutputSettings.html#prettyPrint%28boolean%29)

---

## Answer 4 *(no bullet)*

**No!** Jsoup is one of the **best** and most **capable** Html library out there!

Comment: Wow, thanks for very detailed answer! I'm a bit out of context of this problem at the moment, but will have a look at this later.