# Replace chars in String but avoid allowed HTML tags

Tags: java

I have a String which can contain `HTML Code` like this:

```
String description = "<strong> HI </strong> all, <br /> here some other special chars <  >  \" and Html tag which is not allowed <b> </b>;
```

I have an Array of allowed HTML values which needs be kept in this String:

```
String[] allowedValues = {"<br />", "<strong>", "</strong>", "<u>", "</u>",
                                "<i>", "</i>", "<li>", "</li>", "<ul>", "</ul>", 
                                "&lt;", "&gt;", "&amp;", "&qout;" ,"&apos;"};
```

All other HTML tags or special chars must be replaced in this way:

```
StringUtils.replaceEach(str, new String[]{"&", "\"", "<", ">"}, new String[]{"&amp;", "&quot;", "&lt;", "&gt;"})
```

But the `allowedValues` must not be changed.

How can I avoid changing the `allowedValues`?

Comment: Use a HTML parser tool like jsoup.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I think the OP is not trying to parse it but in way trying to sanitize it.

Comment: @BheshGurung not sure if that's the real OP intention, but then it should use [OWASP Html Sanitizer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project) instead of home brewing a tool like this. If not, then OP should provide more info about the problem to solve.

Comment: @BheshGurung OP could also look into sanitizing with JSoup http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer

Comment: @SMT: You are correct. I also found this http://stackoverflow.com/q/9364540/738746, which seems related to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @SMT , the JSoup library is what I need. My solution looks like this.

I created a enum for different use cases, because some of the HTMl Strings has other allowed tags.

```
import org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist;

public enum StringModifier {

    DETAIL {
        @Override
        public Whitelist whitelist() {
                return new Whitelist()
                    .addTags("strong", "i", "li", "ul", "br", "u", "b", "a")
                    .addAttributes("a", "href");
        }
    },

    TEASER {
        @Override
        public Whitelist whitelist() {
                return new Whitelist()
                    .addTags();
        }
    },

    INCLUSIVE {
        @Override
        public Whitelist whitelist() {
                return new Whitelist()
                    .addTags("strong", "i", "li", "ul", "br", "u", "b");
        }
    },

    DOCINFO {
        @Override
        public Whitelist whitelist() {
                return new Whitelist()
                    .addTags("br", "li", "ul");
        }
    },

    INTERNAL {
        @Override
        public Whitelist whitelist() {
                return new Whitelist()
                .addTags(
                        "a", "b", "blockquote", "br", "caption", "cite", "code", "col",
                        "colgroup", "dd", "div", "dl", "dt", "em", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6",
                        "i", "img", "li", "ol", "p", "pre", "q", "small", "span", "strike", "strong",
                        "sub", "sup", "table", "tbody", "td", "tfoot", "th", "thead", "tr", "u",
                        "ul")

                .addAttributes("a", "href", "title")
                .addAttributes("blockquote", "cite")
                .addAttributes("col", "span", "width")
                .addAttributes("colgroup", "span", "width")
                .addAttributes("img", "align", "alt", "height", "src", "title", "width")
                .addAttributes("ol", "start", "type")
                .addAttributes("q", "cite")
                .addAttributes("table", "summary", "width")
                .addAttributes("td", "abbr", "axis", "colspan", "rowspan", "width")
                .addAttributes(
                        "th", "abbr", "axis", "colspan", "rowspan", "scope",
                        "width")
                .addAttributes("ul", "type")

                .addProtocols("a", "href", "ftp", "http", "https", "mailto")
                .addProtocols("blockquote", "cite", "http", "https")
                .addProtocols("cite", "cite", "http", "https")
                .addProtocols("img", "src", "http", "https")
                .addProtocols("q", "cite", "http", "https")
                ;
        }
    },

    OTHER {
        @Override
        public Whitelist whitelist() {
                return new Whitelist()
                    .addTags();
        }
    };

    public abstract Whitelist whitelist();

}
```

And after sanitizing the String I replace some tags for my needs.

```
public class ModifyString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        modifyStringValue("", "DETAIL", "<b>Day 1 Supertöllertag </b> <a href=iwmefwfe.de>  <table> < > ; ");
    }

    public static String modifyStringValue (String scope, String objectType, String description){
        description = Jsoup.clean(description,StringModifier.valueOf(objectType).whitelist());
        description = StringUtils.replaceEach(description.toString(), 
                new String[]{"<br>", "<p>", "<b>", "</b>", "&nbsp;"},
                new String[]{"<br />", "<br /><br />", "<strong>", "</strong>", " "});

        System.out.println(description);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
<strong>Day 1 Supertöllertag </strong> <a href="iwmefwfe.de">  &lt; &gt; ; </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to use regular expressions instead.

Here you have an example [Regular expression to remove HTML tags from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229831/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-string)

Comment: I am not totally agree. With a delimited set of tags, its safe to use this method. I have used it many times without problems.